# Is array serialization always bad idea?

Tags: database-design, performance, application-design

I'm making form-generating app in php. I have Widget table with type_id (html input) field, and I would like to add options field, like width/height, step, range, etc. Different widgets do have different options though.

I can think of two options:

1. Use separate meta table for every input type (20+)
2. Use serialized array as a meta

Option 1 seem more "legal", but option 2 would be easier to implement and maintain(?).

Would performance be considerably better with option 1?

EDIT: This widget table will be accessed only through widget_id and used to render html. Changes are possible, but they shouldn't happen that often.

Comment: I don't understand how your front-end design should affect your back-end? Can you explain how the two are connected?

Comment: Users in application are generating custom forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually plan to query these attributes separately (such as "Find all form elements with height = 20 and colour = #FF3377") then it is probably better to store them in some kind of queryable attributes table. If you are only plan to use a set of attributes as a whole, and never query inside it, never update/insert/delete individual attributes for specific form elements, then serializing the array and storing it as a BLOB (or something) might not be so bad, as it would keep your design simpler.